PBKDF2 HMACSHA512 C# and Java differences
My partner is using https://github.com/realindiahotel/PWDTK.NET to encode passwords of users.
We plan to import those users to another application, and we have to use same encoders. My application is Spring Boot.
I have problems with getting same hash as he does.
String salt = "F2ZEAo/UMjzIJwNvCC6cRwObd4CX462BTv4Tn/ntaTad6P8Xej1VNqlwNdueYo/XklYPH2RDfLUjsa/dkqnQzg==";

String hash = "hwuR4Ol/tVi9DxRsjAstLt+wfJsTMr+ZzOBh3X90pAmhZU2gyeOngE7OMbQuVB/VYjj+47IqtIYffJ9CHfV7TQ==";

Password for this is "123456".
His code (C#):
public static HashedPassword GetNewPassword(string plainPassword)
    {

    byte[] randomSalt = PWDTK.GetRandomSalt();
    byte[] hash = PWDTK.PasswordToHash(randomSalt, plainPassword);
    return new HashedPassword { PasswordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash), Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(randomSalt) };
}

My code (Java):
    public static boolean matches(String rawPassword, String storedHash, String storedSalt) throws NoSuchProviderException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        byte[] decodedHash = Base64.getDecoder().decode(storedHash.getBytes());

        System.out.println("hash " + Hex.encodeHexString(decodedHash));

        byte[] decodedSalt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(storedSalt.getBytes());
        System.out.println("salt " + Hex.encodeHexString(decodedSalt));

        try {

            PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(rawPassword.toCharArray(), decodedSalt, 5000, 512);
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
            SecretKey generatedKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            byte[] generatedHash = generatedKey.getEncoded();
            System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(generatedHash));
            return MessageDigest.isEqual(decodedHash, generatedHash);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

I have tried several online PBKDF2 tools and they all return same hash as Java.
https://onlinephp.io/c/3304b
For salt "F2ZEAo/UMjzIJwNvCC6cRwObd4CX462BTv4Tn/ntaTad6P8Xej1VNqlwNdueYo/XklYPH2RDfLUjsa/dkqnQzg==" and plain password "123456" and 5000 iterations I get "5281e548c33c0fece48967900b6af8dcfc66d7266fbede24be918192d3feb1437827e7c1c0b93c289abb805fbbfb76d66b512082f74b76061f5bd21d9d41d0ad" as result.
What could be differences?

Here you can find test vectors for PBKDF2/HMAC/SHA512. E.g. test case 5, this can be reproduced with the Java code, but not with the C# code and the PWDTK library. Possibly the PWDTK library contains a bug. Why don't you use the built-in Rfc2898DeriveBytes class?

For .NET versions where Rfc2898DeriveBytes with HMAC/SHA512 is not available, BouncyCastle is an option.

correct. PWDTK clearly contains a bug that it works different than other libraries. I have tried BouncyCastle, native Java, some online testers, and they all returned one hash.
i ended up writing Rfc2898 class that would work same as one in PWDTK library. It finally works, not correct. but it work same way as on partners application. I will import those hashes and salts, so that was important.
Rfc2898 implementation compatible with PWDTK : https://pastebin.com/jwmG9MUP

I'd never name my classes after an RFC that contains multiple algorithms. Just name it PBKDF2 or something similar (note that the RFC also contains PBKDF1, for instance). Yes, that means that Microsoft screwed up the naming.

sure, i plan to rename it. only thing that matters for me is that it works :)
